# "Is a field but used like a Type" C# Error

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I'm trying to use ProcessStartInfo class object to run a command. This is how I'm make the call to run the Process. When I tried to set UseShellExecute to False I get an error which says **startInfo**  is a filed but used like a Type ? I read another answer which says this should be added as Constructor, but that still shows an error. Can anyone give me suggestions on what it means ?

```
   ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(NETDOM_EXE,args);
   **startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;** // ERROR_LINE
   Process p = Process.Start(startInfo);

        if (!p.WaitForExit(120))
        {
            p.Kill();                
        }

        int exitCode = p.ExitCode;
        if (exitCode != 0)
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Exit Code: " + exitCode);
        }
```

Comment: The code appears to be fine, are NETDOM_EXE and args strings?

Comment: Yes, NETDOM_EXE is "netdom.exe" and args is generated command line args for netdom in this format -http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc788049.aspx

Comment: Just checking, but is your code inside of a method?  You can get this error when your code is outside of a method.

Comment: This is shown by Intellisense.The error I get is "ConsoleApplication2.Program.startInfo is a 'field' but used like a 'type'"

Comment: @Learner That means you've put that code directly inside the `Program` class declaration, instead of putting it inside a method of the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put that code inside your `static void Main(...)` method and see if that eliminates the compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

You will get that error if the code is not inside of a method.

In order to have it run on start, you either need the code in the `static void Main()` or call the method with your code from `static void Main()`